# Conditional Data Validation - Returning a list of entries based on availability

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, formula

In **column A, **I have a list of *names*, and in **column B, **a list of *nicknames*.  Not every name will have a corresponding nickname.

[image: names and nicknames]

The following formula generates a list of the names in column A while substituting nicknames from column B in every case where there is one:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B$8), $A$2:$A$8, $B$2:$B$8)
```

However, when I use this formula to generate a list for data validation, it produces an error.  Is it possible, (preferably without VBA), to recreate this functionality in a format that data validation will accept?  I've had trouble "phrasing" this issue in Google and haven't found a solution.

I've tried using the previous formula in the data validation, but it results in an error:

> The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you wish to continue?

I've also tried concatenating the results of the formula into a comma-delimited string, but it looks like data validation won't parse the string after parsing the formula and results in the entire string being the only validated option.

Comment: `=D2#` In your data validation list (you need to create the actual spill range to be able to refer to it).

Comment: Hi @P.b, D2 is just an example of the desired list, it doesn't actually exist in my project.  All I have to work with are the two separate lists in columns A and B.

Comment: I believe what @P.b means is that you can create a "helper" column of data, exactly as you've done in Column D. Then use the names in Column D in your data validation list. If you want that validation list to be "hidden", move it out to Column XX or on another (possibly hidden) sheet entirely.

Comment: I would rather avoid helper or hidden columns to try to keep things neat.

Comment: Using a hidden sheet as suggested is perfectly neat. Also, if you don't want them to be shown as you have it now, how are you trying to use it?

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to compile a list of names and nicknames to be used as data validation for another part of the project.  I would not consider an entire extra sheet as neat, especially if there's a way to do this directly.

Comment: You have no choice. A Data Validation List must consist of either hard-coded, comma-separated entries or else a reference to an actual worksheet range.

Comment: You ask for how to do it and we give the solution. As you can see in my comment, that of PeterT,  Notus_Panda and Jos Woolley, to accomplish this with a formula, you can't do it directly in the data validation list. It requires either hardcoded entries, or range input. You can refer to a spill range like in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking actually IS possible.

By using the 'custom' criteria in the data validation window, you can write a formula that tests if the entered argument is part of the list.

However, the 'custom' formula cannot simply be a list itself, but has to return a TRUE or FALSE value directly.

For example, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: example]

The formula used is:

```
=OR(G3=IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B$9),$A$2:$A$9,$B$2:$B$9))
```

So this formula test if any items of the list that you specified through the IF function is equal to G3, the cell on which the data validation itself is applied.

Moreover, if you have a whole range that shall have this type of data validation, you do not have to rewrite the data validation for every cell. By using a relative reference G3 (instead of absolute reference $G$3) the data validation will automatically apply correctly to each cell of the range

Comment: This is very close, thank you!  Is it possible to do it this way while also utilizing a drop down menu like with the 'List' option?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think so. Without using VBA, I guess you will have to either solve it through a helper array which allows drop down menu, or through the custom criterium but without drop down

Comment: So it turns out you can actually use formulas in the 'list' section of the data validation as well (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akz8i.png)), but then the drop down doesn't show anything.

Comment: Yeah, I figure the problem is this formula can only tell you if an entry is correct, not what the list of entries actually is, so there's no way to create a dropdown.  I might have to resort to VBA.